# SQL output in one row

Tags: sql

For example, I "select * from posts where id = 2"
It will output all of the "id 2" information in 1 row
[image]

After normalization, it have a new table for many to many relation.
but I want to know that how can I output the result such as before normalization?
Or I need to modify the output in backend code?

[image]

thanks

Comment: This is sql-server or mysql?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is `group_concat()`, which puts all the values in a single row:

```
select p.*, group_concat(t.name) as tags
from posts p join
     tag_post tp
     on tp.post_id = p.id join
     tag t
     on tp.tag_id = t.id
group by p.id;
```

Note:  This assumes that `posts(id)` is declared as the primary key (or at least `unique`) so you can use `select p.*` with `group by`.